# Do not enter in submit() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a function that sends the form via AJAX, but does not enter the .submit function of the form. what am I doing wrong?

That's my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  debugger;
  console.log('doc'); // Enter here!
  $('#formClient').submit(function() {
    console.log('submit'); // Not enter here!
    // var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();
    // $.ajax({
    //     type: 'POST',
    //     url: '../client/clientRegisterEdit.php',
    //     data: dados,
    //     success: function(data){
    //         alert(data);
    //     }
    // });
    // return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="<?php //echo urlClientRegisterEdit ?> " method="post" id="formClient" name="formClient" onsubmit="">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar
                 </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Código:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" aria-describedby="helpId" placeholder="">
        <!-- Others inputs here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try removing your unnecessary `onsubmit=""`

Comment: When I run your code it enters the function and logs `submit`. Is that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Barmar It was to send the form via AJAX and keep it on the same screen, but neither send the form nor it stays on the same screen.
It does not execute what's inside the jquery .submit () call

Comment: Taplar I tried, it's no use ...

Comment: Lol, in my project do not enter the form .submit (), more here in the snippet came in .. Why?

Comment: Inside `action=" "`, the php file is unavailable

Comment: Also, please provide us with ALL of your code. This seems to be a part of it. The problem could be in another part. Could you also explain your problem better?

Comment: @Rojo I have already placed the normal url in the action = "", but it still does not work. The problem is that in my project it does not enter into the jquery function .submit (). The rest is right, in a nutshell.

Comment: @RBalconi what I'm trying to say is that we can't see the PHP file

Comment: @Rojo https://pastebin.com/9DH7vSwF Here, my php file, the "../client/clientRegisterEdit.php". 

But regardless of the php file does not go into function, there is nothing to do, or does it have?

Comment: It seems to me that you need `prevent default` --  IE `$('#formClient').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // put AJAX stuff here
  });`

Comment: @Zak not work :(

Comment: See the debug, it arrives at the .submit () it jumps and exits the function ..
https://imgur.com/a/lvQM00D

Comment: Maybe another js file is hooking your code, some class or id?

Comment: @RBalconi We cannot retrieve the .php file, causing an error to appear that does not relate to the problem you are describing